# using Arraylist.add() function in a loop

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a notifications fragment in Android application, for that i have  a firebase database like the following

```
{
  "comments" : {
    "-M5TzP6GKDal61bEUY66" : {
      "-M5bP5nDhmEcHRij05SE" : {
        "comment" : "salaaaam",
        "username" : "snoussi khalil"
      }
    },
    "-M5co-nrZ8RxdFiuR_Vl" : {
      "-M5co92GjJDbs5mqTnp1" : {
        "comment" : "first",
        "username" : "omar kinani"
      },
      "-M5co9TwnSqcNzELI46x" : {
        "comment" : "first",
        "username" : "omar kinani"
      },
      "-M5coCPjicyKVeEC61B1" : {
        "comment" : "first",
        "username" : "omar kinani"
      },
      "-M5coE2WHdGrBGEi1QCn" : {
        "comment" : "first",
        "username" : "omar kinani"
      },
      "-M5coj-Z8jPekGDre3Ie" : {
        "comment" : "yea",
        "username" : "omar kinani"
      }
    }
  },
  "posts" : {
    "-M5TbWiSlgN7lW4_vJkm" : {
      "author" : "snoussi khalil",
      "lat" : 34.0401902,
      "longt" : -4.9937379,
      "txt" : "hello there guys"
    },
    "-M5TjFWG7abQnap0IOPH" : {
      "author" : "snoussi khalil",
      "lat" : 34.0401842,
      "longt" : -4.9937646,
      "txt" : "bonjor"
    },
    "-M5TzP6GKDal61bEUY66" : {
      "author" : "snoussi khalil",
      "lat" : 34.0401748,
      "longt" : -4.9937932,
      "txt" : "dude"
    },
    "-M5co-nrZ8RxdFiuR_Vl" : {
      "author" : "omar kinani",
      "txt" : "hey"
    }
```

and to retrieve comments of posts which the author equals the user id i made two for loops and tried to append an Arraylist with comments of each post. my problem is : my Arraylist is empty outside the loop but contains elements **inside the loop**, i know because i used a LOG.d() function to look closely what's happening.

```
public class NotifFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference postRef;
    private DatabaseReference comRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private List<String> comments;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification,container,false);
         //database init
         database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
         postRef = database.getReference("posts");
         comRef = database.getReference("comments");
         //user init
         mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
         final String username = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();


         //init an empty arraylist for comments

        comments = new ArrayList<>();

         postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 for (final DataSnapshot keynode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String author = keynode.child("author").getValue(String.class);
                    if (author.equals(username)){
                        comRef.child(keynode.getKey()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                                for (DataSnapshot item:dataSnapshot1.getChildren()){
                                    String comment = item.child("comment").getValue(String.class);
                                    Log.d("sos",""+comment+"and list size: "+comments.size());
                                    comments.add(comment);


                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                 }

             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         });

         Log.d("sos","your final list size is : "+comments.size());



        return  view;
    }
}
```

I've executed the application and added dummy comments into a post three comments `"first"` and the fourth is yea the arraylist actually got bigger inside the loop but get to size zero when finally outside the loop.

**and the LOGCAT:**

```
12020-04-23 22:12:49.372 1664-1664/com.snoussi.univox D/sos: your final list size is : 0
2020-04-23 22:12:51.340 1664-1664/com.snoussi.univox D/sos: firstand list size: 0
2020-04-23 22:12:51.341 1664-1664/com.snoussi.univox D/sos: firstand list size: 1
2020-04-23 22:12:51.342 1664-1664/com.snoussi.univox D/sos: firstand list size: 2
2020-04-23 22:12:51.343 1664-1664/com.snoussi.univox D/sos: firstand list size: 3
2020-04-23 22:12:51.344 1664-1664/com.snoussi.univox D/sos: yeaand list size: 4
```

Comment: Your final list size is after receiving and parsing (in the loop), so at the end of `onDataChange` method. At the end of your `onCreateView` list is empty becaue not received data yet.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @RobOhRob there is problem that you are receiving data in listener which can be called e.g. 2 minutes after inflating and executing `onCreateView method.

Comment: @Boken ok, but how do i make a constant copy of my final arraylist ? i want to use it to make a ListView.

Comment: @RobOhRob yes i did but i didn't  get anything since i don't experience a crash.

Comment: @KhalilSnoussi you have to fill your `RecyclerView` in the last line of `onDataChange()` method. Becaue there is a place where you HAVE data. Not earlier.

Comment: @Boken, thank you very much dude it worked, can you explain why outside the listener the arraylist is empty ?

Comment: Add a comment inside `onDataChange` - as first line (WHERE you are receiving data) and as a last line of `onCreateView`. And check what is first. You need some time to receive data, that is the reason why at the end of `onCreateView()` is empty (because you did not receive any data yet.

Comment: @Boken thanks i understood you slay.

Comment: @KhalilSnoussi added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving data some time later. Inflating layout is faster than fetching data from Firebase.

So yes, at the end of the `onCreateView()` method list is empty beacuse you will receive them later (in the listener).

When you need to display data in some list, you have to do in `onDataChange()` method:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Parse data
    // Show data in the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a Listener, there is a delay between when the data collected and when you display the list. so no data is there because of the delay

you can see it in your logs - first you see it:com.snoussi.univox D/sos: your final list size is : 0 Although it written after the other logs

Comment: glad I could help